# Who is dressed as a cadet in Final Fantasy VIII?

Tags: video-games, final-fantasy

> The train goes back to Timber. Meanwhile, an G-Army officer is
> lecturing.]
>
> Galbadian Soldier: "A guy dressed as a cadet... Gathering
> information?"
>
> Galbadian Soldier 2: "He was asking about the president's stay! I
> found it strange that a cadet would keep asking about the president.
> He was very polite and kept addressing me as 'sir'."
>
> Galbadian Soldier 3: "I think I know who you're talking about! He was
> taking care of 3 suspicious looking characters from Balamb! I'll go
> question every teenager in the area!!!"
>
> [The third soldier runs off.]
>
> Galbadian Soldier: "No! We can't just go up to anybody and... Ahem.
> These are citizens. We can't inflict any..."
>
> Galbadian Soldier 2: "How dare they try to kidnap the president! Not
> only is it disrespectful to the president, but also to us Galbadian
> soldiers as well! I'll be sure to find 'em and throw their sad
> be-hinds in jail!!!"
>
> [The other two soldiers run off to find their be-hinds.]
>
> Galbadian Soldier: "...Please... Hear me out...to the very end..."
>
> [Back at the train station, everyone disembarks.]
>
> Watts: "...Say! I remember now, sir! I think the [TV Station] is
> located behind a building called [Timber Maniacs]! Please head in that
> direction, sir! I hope you find it!"

Who is this guy dressed as a cadet?

Comment: I have a strange feeling this question had already been posted earlier today.

Answer (score 4):

It's **Watts**. You talk to him a lot during this part of the game and he ends a LOT of his sentences with the word "sir". He also mentions to your party just a few lines before this exchange that "Gathering information is my specialty, sir!". He also provides a lot of detailed info about the president.

I got this info from the compiled game script at https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps/197343-final-fantasy-viii/faqs/44121 by searching for "Watts".

Comment: But Watts is not dressed as a cadet..

Comment: It's implied that he is disguised as a cadet when talking to the soldiers off-screen. He is does not look like one in any of the game cutscenes.